# (Django) Enviar formulário para outra tabela

Tags: django

Sou iniciante no Django e estou apanhando muito em uma coisa. Quero enviar um formulário que já foi preenchido para outra tabela. Preciso de alguma forma para selecionar qual tabela o formulário será enviado, e que ele "vá" com todos os dados que já foram inseridos posteriormente.

Toda vez que um formulário novo é criado, ele vai pra página inicial:[image: Formulario]Percebam que a informação já foi inserida. Eu quero pegar a mesma informação, selecionar a Class do Model, e enviar para a selecionada.

pretendo fazer uma espécie de sistema de pendencias para enviar pra outras pessoas/setores.

Meu Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Solicitacao(models.Model):
  nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  carteira = models.CharField(max_length=17)
  atendimento = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  descricao = models.TextField()
  data_da_solicitacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
  telefone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
  arquivo = models.FileField(upload_to='documentos/%y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)


  def __str__(self):
     return str(self.id)

  class Sala1(models.Model):
     nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     carteira = models.CharField(max_length=17)
     atendimento = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     descricao = models.TextField()
     data_da_solicitacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     documentos = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
     email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
     telefone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
     arquivo = models.FileField(upload_to='documentos/%y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)

     def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

     class Sala2(models.Model):
        nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        carteira = models.CharField(max_length=17)
        atendimento = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        descricao = models.TextField()
        data_da_solicitacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        documentos = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
        email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
        telefone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
        arquivo = models.FileField(upload_to='documentos/%y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
          return str(self.id)

     class Sala3(models.Model):
         nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
         carteira = models.CharField(max_length=17)
         atendimento = models.CharField(max_length=100)
         descricao = models.TextField()
         data_da_solicitacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
         active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
         user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         documentos = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
         email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
         telefone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
         arquivo = models.FileField(upload_to='documentos/%y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)

         def __str__(self):
             return str(self.id)
```

View.py: Na view eu não tenho a mínima ideia do que por pra fazer isso funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo sentido na implementação das classes Sala1, Sala2 e Sala3, sendo que é a mesma modelagem da classe Solicitação. Não entendi bem o objetivo do seu sistema, mas independente disso, ter mais de uma tabela com exatamente a mesma estrutura, além de não fazer sentido, não me parece ser uma boa prática para o seu projeto.

Ex.: Se cada solicitação cadastrada for vinculada a uma sala, você pode criar um app Sala, criar o Model correspondente e, na solicitação, criar um campo do tipo ForeignKey.

Os dados serão gravados na tabela correspondente ao Model utilizado na View. Por exemplo, se você cria uma View para cadastro de solicitação, você vai carregar o Model de solicitação na sua View, e em seguida implementar o código para realizar o cadastro. Essa View será chamada pela URL que você registra. No seu formulário, você fará um POST para o endereço configurado em url.py. A url em questão chamará a View correspondente. O mesmo vale para edição, deleção, listagem e o que mais você precisar implementar.

Uma sequência de vídeos que consumi quando estava no início é esse aqui:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIvnNCQnejw&list=PLHWfNMxB2F4HdKbo8zdgXyxVDOxH429Ko

Acredito que consiga sanar suas dúvidas iniciais.

Abraços,